# set content of textarea in wtforms

Tags: flask, textarea, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I want to change the content of a textArea created with wtforms ( in flask ). How can I do this?
I used this way to change the content of the text field

```
{{ form.title(value="this is the value") }}
```

but it does not work for the textarea field

sorry, I can't speak English very well, but I hope I got my point across

Comment: You may want to set the value via the form's [`data`](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/forms/#wtforms.form.Form.__init__) parameter. By passing a dictionary, you can assign a field value to each form field. The documentation gives you a lot of other ways to set the value of a form field, such as the `obj` parameter or using keyword arguments.

Answer (score 0):

No way.

If you want to change field data, do it in the code

```
form.title.data = "this is the value"
```

or set some value in form definition

```
class MyForm():
    title = StringField(widget=TextArea(), default="this is the value")
```